# Java Rest Client for Jira Zephyr API?

Tags: java, jira, rest-client, jira-zephyr

is there a Java REST Client for JIRA Zephyr, similiar to the [REST Java Client for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.jira-rest-java-client/server/overview)? Another helpful approch would be a YAML-File or another kind of webservice description to generate a rest client from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Jira server or Jira cloud? 
If you are using Jira server, the answer to your question is yes: ZAPI

You can find it on the Atlassian Marketplace, it is an "add-on to Zephyr for JIRA allows access to its testing data programmatically via RESTful APIs"

If you are using Jira Cloud the answer is no. not yet. 
The api access feature has been in the works for a long time, and even though their site says it is just released in beta, they pulled it.  I have been talking with Zephyr tech reps about that all this last week.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm actually looking for a webservice description of the ZAPI (e.g. YAML, RAML, ...).